# error in creating AVD android 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I've created successfully AVD for Nexus one. but After the creation , I get an error below the windows , saying: A repairable Andorid Virtual Device....

when I run the application - it does run ,but I cannot see the device buttons in the emulator

thank you for your help !